# Linear semi transparent gradient background (pure css)

Tags: html, css

How to create such a fading text effect before text is restricted:
[image]

**in pure css**.

I would prefer to append the style into a box below the fading text.

Shall I operate on border box or other element? Any piece of code compatible with all browsers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. You can make it using `::after` element with `position: absolute;`, and it will overlap text in a container.

With this CSS you can add `.short-box` to any block and it will receive your desired gradient fade.

```css
.short-box {
  /* if you want to hide a part of text */
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for :after to follow the paretn position */
  position: relative;
}

.short-box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* here you can use `%` instead of `px`, so this block height will depends on parent height */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="short-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: If I want to apply that to the container that follows the text, how the code would look like?

Example:

<p> text I want to be faded by the short-box </p>

<div class="short-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
</div>

Comment: `<p class="short-box"> text I want to be faded by the short-box </p>` or `<div class="short-box"><p> text I want to be faded by the short-box </p></div>` both will work